# Python Raw SQL query is returning values enclosed inside [('...'),]

Tags: python, django, view, models, rawsql

I am facing an issue while using raw SQL queries in Django.

In views.py, the following function is defined:

```
def functionSQL():

    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select column_name from "table_name" where CONDITION')
    value = cursor.fetchall()
    return value
```

> The value is returned as
>   **[('returned_value'),]** instead of **returned_value**

Is there something I am missing here ?
How can I remove the unnecessary prefix and suffix from the returned value?

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list of result rows, which consists of fields (columns). Your result seems to have one row with one field.

Comment: This is not a Django raw query. This is a raw sql query. If you are going to be writing them. Might as well say good by to django

Comment: I can write fetchone() instead of fetchall(), but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not *prefixes* and *suffixes*. The return value of `.fetchall()` is always a **list of tuples**, whether it returns a single value or multiple rows and columns. From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html):

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it returns an empty list.

That being said, you can return a single value from your function using something like this:

```
def functionSQL():
    ...
    value = cursor.fetchall()
    return value[0][0] if value != [] else value
```